# Windows Certificates - where is private key located?

Tags: certificates, cryptography, public-key-infrastructure, windows-10, pfx

In Windows 10:

When I load a certficate into the "Current User" store, it puts a private key file here:

```
C:\Users\[userID-A]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-xxx\pkfileqreflr8029r...
```

When I load a certficate into the "Local Machine" store using a different UserID-B, I don't see this path at all:

`C:\Users\[userID-B]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto ...`   there is no \Crypto folder created.

Does anyone know where the private key is stored when a pfx file is used to import a cert into the Local Machine store? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The locations are listed in Microsoft Docs on [Key Storage and Retrieval](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval).

For *Local system private* the locations are:

- The Microsoft legacy CryptoAPI CSPs store private keys in:

  ```
  %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18\
  %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\DSS\S-1-5-18\
  ```
- CNG stores private keys in:

  ```
  %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys
  ```

In practice they are by default under `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\` on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks. For me, %ALLUSERSPROFILE% maps to c:\ProgramData. The full path looks a little different but gets me to the correct area:  c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\...